# SQL- Finding Orders with only certain items

Tags: sql, percentage

I have an order table with a row for each item in every order. Order number is in each row (not unique of course). Item number is unique.  I need to find orders that have ONLY 100% of a certain type of item - lets say "candy".  So if an order has 10 items in it and all 10 of them are candy, I want some information about that order out of those rows. If a 10 item order has 9 items of candy and 1 item of shoes, I don't want any information from any of that order.  My SQL skills are pretty mediocre when it comes to calculations other than very basic. So how would I do this? Thank you!

Sample `orders` table:

```
ORD_NUM    ITEM    CATGRY    COST
123        567        CANDY     $4 
123        489        CANDY     $5 
123        990        CANDY     $9 
987        222        SHOES     $10 
987        990        CANDY     $9 
987        567        CANDY     $4
```

Expected results:
count of orders:         2
orders with 100% candy:    1
cost of orders with 100% candy:    $18

I don't have a starting query except how to find the candy items, but I'm getting all of them.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Tag the dbms you're using. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: `SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM [ORDER] GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(1) = count(case when Item_Type = 'Candy' then 1 end)`  basically check that the number of items on an order matches the number of items on an order having a `candy` type.  this gives you a list of orders you want data about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added sample data so we had 2 orders with 100% candy... and more without.

[WORKING SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49da11/1/0)

```
SELECT ORD_NUM, sum(cost) as Sum_Cost
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ORD_NUM
HAVING COUNT(1) = count(Case when Catgry = 'CANDY' then 1 end);
```

If you need to aggregate ALL you could wrap this query in an outer query which simply counts the order_nums....

```
SELECT COUNT(ORD_NUM), sum(Sum_cost) as Sum_cost
FROM (SELECT ORD_NUM, sum(cost) as Sum_Cost
      FROM ORDERS
      GROUP BY ORD_NUM
      HAVING COUNT(1) = count(Case when Catgry = 'CANDY' then 1 end)
     ) OrderCost;
```

**How this works:**

We use simple aggregation to get a count of all items on an order and all items on an order that are candy. We compare those two values, and if they match then we know the order is 100% candy.  If they don't match, then we know the order has at least 1 non-candy item and can excluded the WHOLE order.

Since I wasn't sure if you wanted the cost of each order summed individually, or all orders summed, I provided both methods.

Comment: Lets look at order 987.   `count(1)` will be 3 since there are 3 items on the order.  `Count(Case when catgry='CANDY' then 1 end)` will be 2 since there are 2 candy and 1 shoe. 3<> 2 so the entire order is eliminated.  The SQL Fiddle link at top shows this working.  Make sense?  if not keep asking!

Comment: Think of `Having` as just another where clause with which you can limit data but after the aggregation has been done.  you can't aggregate in the where clause (unless you use subqueries), but you can in the having!

Comment: YOU are the freakin bomb!  Thank you so much, that is perfect!

Comment: And your "think of having" comment just cleared that up for me, thanks again!